# Setting nginx reverse proxy with rewrite to apply to all links in site

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I have the following Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /test {
        rewrite /test(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass "http://www.example.com/";
    }
}
```

This works well for the home page and when entering 'http://localhost/test' I get the content of http://www.example.com/ and the URL remains 'http://localhost/test'.

Cool, but when I hit a link in the website, say `/more_examples` I want the link to be rewritten as such:  http://localhost/test/more_examples.
In practice, I get the following: http://localhost/more_examples, which obviously will not work. Is this even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and for me this works like you describe it:

```
location /test {
  rewrite /test(.*) $1 break;
  proxy_pass http://www.basicwebsiteexample.com;
}
```

I call `http://localhost/test` and for sub pages like this `http://localhost/test/media`.

I don't get any redirect or URL rewriting in my browser.

If you still get an URL redirect in your browser there must be a redirect in the website you're proxying or in your nginx config.